# hadoop 1.x ports list - 4 more unknown ports

Tags: hadoop, networking, mapreduce, hdfs

I configured and installed hadoop 1.2.1 single node. I configured the namenode and jobtracker address with ports as "**hdfs://localhost:9000**" and "**localhost:9001**" respectively.

After starting the cluster (**start-all.sh**). I ran `netstat -nltp` after this, which listed the hadoop ports.

```
50030 - jobtracker Web UI
50060 - tasktracker Web UI
50070 - namenode Web UI
50075 - datanode Web UI
(http://localhost:50075/browseDirectory.jsp?dir=%2F)
50090 - secondary namenode Web UI

54310 - namenode (as configured in XML)
54311 - jobtracker (as configured in XML)
50010 - datanode (for data transfer)
50020 - datanode (for block metadata operations & recovery)
33447 - tasktracker ( not configured. Any unused local port is chosen by hadoop itself)
```

But, a couple of other ports also were occupied and it shows it is java process (I stopped hadoop and confirmed that these belonged to that hadoop cluster only).

```
48212 - ???
41888 - ???
47448 - ???
52544 - ???
```

These are not fixed ports. They are chosen dynamically. Because, when i restarted the cluster (**stop-all.sh** and **start-all.sh**), the other ports were same as first time, except these ports changed

```
48945 - tasktracker (This is fine, as explained before)
```

What about the other ports? What are these ports used for?

```
44117 - ???
59446 - ???
52965 - ???
56583 - ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting this interesting question, Vivek.

It intrigued me a lot and I dig up a bit of code for Apache Hadoop 1.2.1 - startup section for each of the master and slave; 
But there were no additional port bindings except for the standard documented one.

I did a couple of experiments on ways we can start a namenode and observed the ports using `netstat -nltpa`

1) hadoop --config ../conf namenode -regular

2) Directly invoking the Namenode main class

3) Add the default core-default.xml and than start up the namenode

My observation was for #2 and #3 only standard ports showed up, so I looked up the java options and that was the bingo.

Comment all of below in hadoop-env.sh and then start hadoop, you will see only standard port, so the additional ports you see are all JMX bin ports

```
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS"
export HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm from chennai. Did not have access to internet for few days here because of disastrous rain. You answer is what really required for this question (hadoop specific and not netstat related), although the community has given the bounty marks to other person. will check if i can get that for your answer :)
Thanks for that detailed explanation. Now, i got it.

Answer (score 2):

On a `linux` system, known services are typically listed in the `/etc/services` file. This is where network utilities (eg. `netstat`) get's the friendly names for port numbers (ie. 80/http).

Certain packages may update `/etc/services`. If the `hadoop` ports in question have a dynamic range that changes then there would be no reason to perform this update.

#### References

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-which-service-listening-specific-port/
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-appl.services.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -nltp
```

> This shows all the active TCP, UDP, RAW, or Unix socket connections. 
>   Hadoop HDFS, Hbase, Zookeeper creates lot of sockets
>   intermediately and uses for read/write or messaging.
>
> Number of RPC Reader threads gets created in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient 
>   and to read/write data
>   from the connections. hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.ClientProtocol
>   will provide details on how to create socket/factory.